# timeseries dataframe , to increase fixed positions on the first trading day of every month, how to accomplish in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dateframe df as below:

```
date       open      high   low     close
2007/11/02  22757   22855   22564   22620
2007/11/05  22922   22964   22349   22475
2007/11/06  22540   22755   22404   22734
2007/11/07  23058   23251   22811   22929
2007/11/08  22740   22936   22683   22783
... ... ... ... ...
2007/11/28  21841   22040   21703   21776
2007/11/29  22000   22055   21586   21827
2007/11/30  21750   22169   21694   21935
2007/12/03  21782   21935   21469   21527
2007/12/04  21453   21760   21378   21648
2007/12/05  21725   21836   21526   21627
2007/12/06  21460   21787   21454   21632
2007/12/07  21836   21909   21699   21865
... ... ... ... ...
2007/12/26  23352   23556   23298   23456
2007/12/27  23523   23744   23276   23333
2007/12/28  23338   23449   23112   23225
2008/01/02  23225   23388   23174   23183
2008/01/03  23259   23379   23197   23287
2008/01/04  23450   24164   23406   24152

2008/01/24  23079   23386   22969   23292
2008/01/25  23502   23754   23369   23678
2008/01/28  23617   23627   23229   23371
```

Now I want to add a column named POS, it will need to automatically add a fixed position on the first trading day of each month. The desired outcome would be as below:

```
date    open        high    low    close    pos

2007/11/02  22757   22855   22564   22620   100
2007/11/05  22922   22964   22349   22475   100
2007/11/06  22540   22755   22404   22734   100
2007/11/07  23058   23251   22811   22929   100
2007/11/08  22740   22936   22683   22783   100
... ... ... ... ... ...
2007/11/28  21841   22040   21703   21776   100
2007/11/29  22000   22055   21586   21827   100
2007/11/30  21750   22169   21694   21935   100
2007/12/03  21782   21935   21469   21527   200
2007/12/04  21453   21760   21378   21648   200
2007/12/05  21725   21836   21526   21627   200
2007/12/06  21460   21787   21454   21632   200
2007/12/07  21836   21909   21699   21865   200
... ... ... ... ... ...
2007/12/26  23352   23556   23298   23456   200
2007/12/27  23523   23744   23276   23333   200
2007/12/28  23338   23449   23112   23225   200
2008/01/02  23225   23388   23174   23183   300
2008/01/03  23259   23379   23197   23287   300
2008/01/04  23450   24164   23406   24152   300

2008/01/24  23079   23386   22969   23292   300
2008/01/25  23502   23754   23369   23678   300
2008/01/28  23617   23627   23229   23371   300
```

How can I accomplish?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a code snippet of your attempts? How do I ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 4):

Cast your `date` column to DateTime if you haven't yet:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

If the data isn't already sorted by date, make sure to do that (thanks @PiRSquared):

```
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
```

Create the desired column values:

```
df['pos'] = df['date'].dt.month.diff().ne(0).cumsum()*100

df
         date   open   high    low  close  pos
0  2007-11-02  22757  22855  22564  22620  100
1  2007-11-05  22922  22964  22349  22475  100
2  2007-11-06  22540  22755  22404  22734  100
3  2007-11-07  23058  23251  22811  22929  100
4  2007-11-08  22740  22936  22683  22783  100
5  2007-11-28  21841  22040  21703  21776  100
6  2007-11-29  22000  22055  21586  21827  100
7  2007-11-30  21750  22169  21694  21935  100
8  2007-12-03  21782  21935  21469  21527  200
9  2007-12-04  21453  21760  21378  21648  200
10 2007-12-05  21725  21836  21526  21627  200
11 2007-12-06  21460  21787  21454  21632  200
12 2007-12-07  21836  21909  21699  21865  200
13 2007-12-26  23352  23556  23298  23456  200
14 2007-12-27  23523  23744  23276  23333  200
15 2007-12-28  23338  23449  23112  23225  200
16 2008-01-02  23225  23388  23174  23183  300
17 2008-01-03  23259  23379  23197  23287  300
18 2008-01-04  23450  24164  23406  24152  300
19 2008-01-24  23079  23386  22969  23292  300
20 2008-01-25  23502  23754  23369  23678  300
21 2008-01-28  23617  23627  23229  23371  300
```

Comment: This works so long as the months are grouped together.  If the rows happened to be out of order, this would not work.  It's a good answer, but deserves to have that caveat mentioned.  One way to ensure this works is to sort by `date` first.

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you, will edit the sorting caveat into my answer. I saw that the example data was sorted chronologically, but this approach indeed fails on unsorted input.